# Bukhari hadith collection on Sunnah.com

Tags: hadith, sahih-bukhari

In few websites [I came across these ahadith](https://www.al-islam.org/ask-those-who-know-muhammad-al-tijani-al-samawi/chapter-4-concerning-general-companions) (albeit some with slightly different wording):

> In volume 1, in the chapter entitled: "The Fear of the Believer of His
>   Acts being made Futile without him Realizing It,” in "The Book of
>   Faith,” al-Bukhari reported: "Ibrahim al-Tayyimi said: 'Whenever I
>   compare my words with my deeds, I fear I [may] have lied.’ Ibn Abi
>   Mulayka said: 'I met thirty companions of the Prophet (S.A.W.) and
>   each one of them feared hypocrisy within himself. Not one of them
>   could claim to believe in Gabriel or Michael (volume 1, page 97).’”

But I couldn't verify them with the ahadith database of Sunnah.com. Is it because Imam Bukhari had more compilations then listed there?

Comment: It's in there (see §36 under https://www.sunnah.com/bukhari/2). It's just not translated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that the authors of sunnah.com for some strange reasons didn't translate the introductions of the subtitles or subsections in sahih al-Bukhari. They only translated the ahadith which are counted and usually commented by hadith commentators.

As it is there where al-Bukhari mentions some words of wisdom or verses etc. (not necessary ahadith).

For example as posted by @goldPseudo you will find your quotes among the Arabic text in ([2/41](https://sunnah.com/bukhari/2/41)) let's take a closer look at it:

- The title of the "sub-" chapter or subtitle:

  > (36)Chapter: (What is said regarding) the fear of a believer that his good deeds may be annulled (lost) without his knowledge
  >   (36)باب خَوْفِ الْمُؤْمِنِ مِنْ أَنْ يَحْبَطَ عَمَلُهُ وَهُوَ لاَ يَشْعُرُ
- Words of Wisdom or intro for the subtitle/subsection (note I've added the translation from your post and added others too):

  > وَقَالَ **إِبْرَاهِيمُ التَّيْمِيُّ** مَا عَرَضْتُ قَوْلِي عَلَى عَمَلِي إِلاَّ خَشِيتُ أَنْ أَكُونَ مُكَذَّبًا.
  >   **Ibrahim al-Tayyimi** said: 'Whenever I compare my words with my deeds, I fear I [may] have lied.’

  Here two other translations:

  > - Ibrahim al-Tayyimi said: "Whenever I compare my words with my deeds, I fear I [may] be denying [Islam]" (suggested by @@III-AK-III and al-maany for the word مُكَذَّبً: The statement means *he considered his deeds not enough.*)
  > - Ibraaheem al-Taymi (may Allaah have mercy on him) said: When I compare my words with my deeds, I am afraid that my deeds belie my words. (from the fatwa of islamqa)

> وَقَالَ **ابْنُ أَبِي مُلَيْكَةَ** أَدْرَكْتُ ثَلاَثِينَ مِنْ أَصْحَابِ **النَّبِيِّ** صَلَّى اللَّهُ عَلَيْهِ وَسَلَّمَ كُلُّهُمْ يَخَافُ النِّفَاقَ عَلَى نَفْسِهِ، مَا مِنْهُمْ أَحَدٌ يَقُولُ إِنَّهُ عَلَى إِيمَانِ **جِبْرِيلَ** وَ**مِيكَائِيلَ**. [تحفة 15613 ب].
>   **Ibn Abi Mulayka** said: 'I met thirty companions of the **Prophet** (S.A.W.) and each one of them feared hypocrisy within himself. Not one of them could claim to believe in **Gabriel** or **Michael** (In sunnah.com they quoted as a source: Tuhfah تحفة 15613 ba' (b) instead of volume 1, page 97).’”

Here other translations:

> - Ibn Abi Mulaykah said: I met thirty of the companions of the Prophet (peace and blessings of Allaah be upon him) all of whom feared that they might be guilty of hypocrisy, and not one of them said that his faith was like that of Jibreel and Mika’eel. (source the fatwa from islamqa)
>     or
> - Ibn Abi Mulaykah said: I met thirty of the companions of the Prophet (peace and  blessings of Allaah be upon him) all of whom feared that they might be guilty of hypocrisy, andNot one of them could claim to be at the same level of belief as Gabriel or Michael"

And a third word of wisdom which might not have been quoted in your source:

> وَيُذْكَرُ عَنِ **الْحَسَنِ** مَا خَافَهُ إِلاَّ مُؤْمِنٌ، وَلاَ أَمِنَهُ إِلاَّ مُنَافِقٌ. وَمَا يُحْذَرُ مِنَ الإِصْرَارِ عَلَى النِّفَاقِ وَالْعِصْيَانِ مِنْ غَيْرِ تَوْبَةٍ لِقَوْلِ اللَّهِ تَعَالَى: {*وَلَمْ يُصِرُّوا عَلَى مَا فَعَلُوا وَهُمْ يَعْلَمُونَ*}.
>   It was narrated from **al-Hasan**: No one fears it (hypocrisy) but a believer and no one feels safe from it but a hypocrite. And one should be afraid of persisting in hypocrisy and sin without repenting, because Allaah says (interpretation of the meaning): “*and [they] do not persist in what (wrong) they have done, while they know*” (Aal ‘Imraan [3:135](http://legacy.quran.com/3/135)). (Source of the translation: fatwa islamqa [#81874](https://islamqa.info/en/81874))

3. Now they quote the ahadith and their translation (without full sanad=narrator chain):

   > Narrated **'Abdullah**:
   >
   > The Prophet (ﷺ) said, "Abusing a Muslim is Fusuq (an evil doing) and killing him is Kufr (disbelief)."
   >
   > حَدَّثَنَا مُحَمَّدُ بْنُ عَرْعَرَةَ، قَالَ حَدَّثَنَا شُعْبَةُ، عَنْ زُبَيْدٍ، قَالَ سَأَلْتُ أَبَا وَائِلٍ عَنِ الْمُرْجِئَةِ،، فَقَالَ حَدَّثَنِي **عَبْدُ اللَّهِ**، أَنَّ النَّبِيَّ صلى الله عليه وسلم قَالَ ‏ "‏ سِبَابُ الْمُسْلِمِ فُسُوقٌ، وَقِتَالُهُ كُفْرٌ ‏"‏‏.‏

so this is basically how they do. Note also that in sunnah.com they often leave out many useful commentaries of imam at-Tirmidhi, as he often quotes a hadith and then quotes opinions of fiqh or discusses the sanad etc. of the narration. If I have time I could point you to some of my answers where I needed to refer to such statements and needed to translate them myself.

Here examples of left out translations from the original hadith collections, where I needed to translate or at least give a summary of them myself:
Examples of scholarly opinions in jami' at-Tirmidhi:

- A discussion of opinions on the hadith of dhul-Yadain: [When imam forgets in prayer?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/12701/when-imam-forgets-in-prayer/28674#28674)
- An opinion of a-Shafi'i in the comments of at-Tirmidhi: [Does punishment in the worldly life replace punishment in the hereafter?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/40701/does-punishment-in-the-worldly-life-replace-punishment-in-the-hereafter/40704#40704)

Examples of not yet translated ahdith and quotes:

- A fatwa from al-Muwatta' which was not translated: [A husband made a list of demands which prompted his wife to leave Islam; are all of them legally acceptable?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/40727/a-husband-made-a-list-of-demands-which-prompted-his-wife-to-leave-islam-are-all/40742#40742)
- A hadith from sunan an-Nasa'i is quoted only in Arabic the translation is missing: [Are there obsolete hadith?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/43180/are-there-obsolete-hadith/43192#43192)

As the translations on sunnah.com are a work in progress, I hope that one day they might add these helpful comments too.

Comment: "مُكَذَّبًا" means "denier", rather than "liar". Ibrahim al-Tayyimi said: "Whenever I compare my words with my deeds, I fear I [may] be denying [Islam]" meaning he considered his deeds not enough. "مَا مِنْهُمْ أَحَدٌ يَقُولُ إِنَّهُ عَلَى إِيمَانِ جِبْرِيلَ وَمِيكَائِيلَ" means "Not one of them could claim to be at the same level of belief as Gabriel or Michael" meaning they consider their belief level not enough. Translations in al-islam.com of these two quotes are grossly inaccurate.

Comment: In islamqa they translated it: "When I compare my words with my deeds, I am afraid that my deeds belie my words."

Comment: I see well even if al-maany is more for your option (deny) @III-AK-III I personally think the one from islamqa (belie) sounds more likely to be meant.

Comment: This is fine, long as it isn't what the current translation is of calling them liars (I lied) as this is not what the hadith says.