# Isnaad of an Athar

Tags: hadith, reference-request

Assalamou 'Alaikum.

Some people say that the following saying does not have a chain of narration :

> The Tabei Mujahid said:  Istawa (meaning) : Rose (alaa) above the Throne. 
>   Ref [Sahih al Bukhari](https://sunnah.com/bukhari/97/46)

Is it true that the saying of Mujaahid does not have a chain of narration ? And also, if it has a chain of narration, could you please provide it ? Jazaak Allaahu Khayr !

Comment: Note that this is a quote about tafsir in the intro of a chapter or subsection in sahih al-Bukhari so al-Bukhari himself didn't quote a source or sanad https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/45498/bukhari-hadith-collection-on-sunnah-com/45499#45499 .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Interestingly I couldn't find this quote of Mujahid -so far- in any tafssir related to the two Verses quoted in sahih al-Bukhari.

In his [fath al-Bari](https://islamweb.net/ar/library/index.php?page=bookcontents&ID=13575&bk_no=52&flag=1) ibn Hajar al-'Asqalani quoted a chain:

> قوله : وقال مجاهد استوى : علا على العرش ) وصله الفريابي عن ورقاء عن ابن أبي نجيح عنه

Note that this is my own translation take it with the encessary care, I'll only quote the narrator chain:

> Al-Firyabi [محمد بن يوسف الفريابي](https://ar.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D9%85%D8%AD%D9%85%D8%AF_%D8%A8%D9%86_%D9%8A%D9%88%D8%B3%D9%81_%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%81%D8%B1%D9%8A%D8%A7%D8%A8%D9%8A) has narrated (the original wording actually is "connected") it from Warqaa' ورقاء from ibn abi Najih [ابن أبي نجيح](https://ar.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D8%B9%D8%A8%D8%AF_%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%84%D9%87_%D8%A7%D8%A8%D9%86_%D8%A3%D8%A8%D9%8A_%D9%86%D8%AC%D9%8A%D8%AD) from him (meaning Mujahid).

Muhammad ibn Yusuf al-Firyabi is a teacher of imam al-Bukhari (for details see in [siyar a'laam an-Nubalaa'](https://islamweb.net/ar/library/index.php?page=bookcontents&ID=1686&bk_no=60&flag=1)) .

Warqa' is Warqa' ibn 'Omar ورقاء بن عمر ibn Kulayb is also considered as a hafidh and trustworthy (see [siya a'laam an-Nubalaa'](https://islamweb.net/ar/library/index.php?page=bookcontents&ID=1271&bk_no=60&flag=1)).

Abduallah ibn abi Najih actually is a trustworthy narrator and mufassir who has narrated from 'Ata' and Mujahid and was teacher of Sufyan ibn 'Oyayna and Sufyan at-Thawri some considered him from among the [Mu'tazila](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mu%CA%BFtazila), but all agree that when it comes to tafssir he is trustworthy (Summary from [siyar a'laam an-Nubalaa'](https://islamweb.net/ar/library/index.php?page=bookcontents&ID=968&bk_no=60&flag=1) of a-Dhahabi)

The same sanad can also be found in other commentaries such as irshaad as-sari of [al-Qustalani](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Al-Qastallani) and 'Omdat al-Qari of [al-'Ayni](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Badr_al-Din_al-Ayni).